# How to create a global variable if it doesn't exist in Python?

Tags: python

I want to define a Python function doing:
1. Check if a variable already exist.
2. If not, create it as a global variable (because I want to use it outside the function).

```
def foo():
    try:
        x
    except NameError:
        global x
        x = 1
    else:
        pass

foo()
print(x)
```

Then there is an error:

> SyntaxError: name 'x' is used prior to global declaration

How to solve this? Thank you :)

Comment: This doesn't sound like something you should want to do. Why exactly are you trying to do this?

Comment: What did cause this to do so?

Comment: Here are some variable names written in a file, I want to create these variables by reading this file.

Comment: You don't want to have that many variables generated by a file...use a dict instead

Answer (score 4):

Something like this could work.

```
def foo():
    if not('x' in locals()):  
        global x
        x = 1 


foo()
print(x)
```

just check if the x variable exists.

you could also check if a variable is declared as global

```
if not('x' in globals()):
```

Comment: this won't work, since "locals", obviously, do not return the global variables.

Comment: Using " 'x' in globals() " instead of "locals()" is what I want. It works thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just declaring a variable as global at the top of your function won't create it - so this form works:

```
def foo():
    global x
    try:
        x
    except NameError:
        x = 1
```

The key thing to understand here is that when Python compiles a function, it "bakes" each variable inside the function as either a local, nonlocal,  or a global (or builtin) variable - any access to that variable will have either one or the other relevant bytecode.  The "global" declaration thus affects the whole function, regardless of were it is - and since tryig to access a variable before the global statement would look ambiguous, the error you saw is forced.

But since you are at it - are you sure you want to do it? 
global variables are good for having values that can be shared in functions in a module - but then, even if they are to be initialized in the call to an specific function, they should be declared in the module body, and properly documented. If you can't have the final value at module load time, just assign it to None.

Comment: Why the `else` clause?

Comment: Smply but, "global" is a statement meant to be put at the very beggining of your function or method. It may work if put lower, but it is bad practice - and if you try to access teh variable before, you get an error, like you did.